# A Man Invested Some Money at 10% and 12%.............

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A person invested some money at 12% simple interest and some other amount at 10% simple interest. He received yearly interest of Rs.130. If he had interchanged the amounts, he would have received Rs. 40 more as yearly interest. How much did he invest at different rates?

Answer (score 1):

$$0.12\cdot x+0.1\cdot y=130$$
and
$$0.12\cdot y+0.1\cdot x(=130+40)=170$$
Maybe you can solve.

Comment: I tried to solve but I faced problems.

Comment: From the first equality, you have $x=(130-0.1y)/(0.12)$ then replace $x$ by this expression in the second equality.

Comment: I'm getting a wrong answer. Could you plz help out?

Comment: Can the answer by any chance be x=5000 and y=7000 cause thats what is written in my book.

Answer (score -1):

Let the two invested rates be x and y.
Therefore, 12/100*x+10/100*y=130    (Dividing by 100)
          =0.12x+0.1y=130...(i)*0.12
0.1x+0.12y=170...(ii)*0.1
Now solve by yourself to get the answer.

Comment: Very nice and appropriate answer